# Attendance system based on facial recognition

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library, face-recognition, opencv

I am trying to create a face recognition based attendance system but I am getting the error below. If anyone could help I will really appreciate. This is the Code

```py
import os,cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
recognizer = cv2.face_LBPHFaceRecognizer.create()

def getImagesAndLabels(path):
    #get the path of all the files in the folder
    imagePaths=[os.path.join(path,f) for f in os.listdir(path)]
    #create empth face list
    faceSamples=[]
    #create empty ID list
    Ids=[]
    #now looping through all the image paths and loading the Ids and the images
    for imagePath in imagePaths:
        #loading the image and converting it to gray scale
        pilImage=Image.open(path).convert('L')
        #Now we are converting the PIL image into numpy array
        imageNp=np.array(pilImage,'uint8')
        #getting the Id from the image
        Id=int(os.path.split(imagePath)[-1].split(".")[1])
        # extract the face from the training image sample
        faces=detector.detectMultiScale(imageNp)
        #If a face is there then append that in the list as well as Id of it
        for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
            faceSamples.append(imageNp[y:y+h,x:x+w])
            Ids.append(Id)
    return faceSamples,Ids

faces,Ids = getImagesAndLabels('dataSet')
s = recognizer.train(faces, np.array(Ids))
print("Successfully trained")
recognizer.write('trainingData.yml')
```

```
[evaluate training_dataSet.py]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/ADMIN/PycharmProjects/Face-Recognition-Attendance-System/attendance/training_dataSet.py", line 30, in <module>
    s = recognizer.train(faces, np.array(Ids))
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.1) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-i1s8y2i1\opencv_contrib\modules\face\src\lbph_faces.cpp:362: error: (-210:Unsupported format or combination of formats) Empty training data was given. You'll need more than one sample to learn a model. in function 'cv::face::LBPH::train'
```

Comment: Could you maybe provide an example that includes some toy data (e.g. via np.random) that has the shape that you expect the images and labels to have? This would help to pinpoint the issue!

Comment: The likely problem is that your code found no faces.  Have you added debug prints in your loop to see if any faces were found?